# Issue with nested resources in routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a nested resource in my routes config but I just can't work out where the problem lies.

Here is the relevant code from my routes config

```
resources :positions, :only => [:new,:create,:edit,:update,:destroy]

resources :etkh_profiles, :path => "members", :only => [:new,:create,:show,:index] do
  resources :positions
  collection do
    post 'search'
  end
end
```

It works when I try '/positions/new' but when I try 'members/positions/new' I get this error

```
No route matches [GET] "/members/positions/new"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you need to use is more like `/members/:memberid/positions/new` since you've specified that `positions` are contained inside an `etkh_profile`. You can check this by running `rake routes`.